# Replacing values in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, editing

I have a dataframe (named df) as follows:

```
    s01  s03  s06  s07  s08
0   1    1    1    1    1
1   1    1    1    1    1
2   0    1    1    0    1
3   0    0    1    1    0
4   0    0    0    1    1
```

I would like to replace all the ones by its index value.

The final result should look like this:

```
    s01  s03  s06  s07  s08
0   0    0    0    0    0
1   1    1    1    1    1
2   0    2    2    0    2
3   0    0    3    3    0
4   0    0    0    4    4
```

This is just a sample. The real dataframe has thousands of rows and thousands of columns.
The priority is to have an efficient code that modifies the data as quickly as possible.

I have thought of 3 possible ways to solve this:

- Using 2 'for' loops and an 'if' statement and loop over the panda object directly or converting the data to a 2D numpy array and looping over that.
- Using some kind of pandas build-in filtering function over the pandas dataframe.
- Converting the dataframe into a 2D Numpy array and using some kind of numpy build-in function to modify the data.

Which is the most time efficient way?

Is there some other way that is more efficient and I haven't thought of it?

Thank you

Comment: Something else to consider that will really speed up things is to use a dtype that fits in with your data, so if you use only numbers less than 15, use 'int8'. and so forth, since the default data type is int 64. use df.info() to see.  here is an exampe df['s01'] = np.zeros(len(df), dtype='int8')

Comment: Hi, oppressionslayer. Initially, I also thought about that. In fact, the number of rows is in the order of 3000-4000, so an int 64 type would be ok. The issue is that I know from numpy that doing matrix multiplications of ints take longer than with floats. It is because numpy has different methods for ints and floats, and it apparently is more time efficient with floats. Since pandas is built around numpy, I dont know it converting into ints is a good idea. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with `mask`:

```
df.mask(df.eq(1), df.index)
```

Output:

```
   s01  s03  s06  s07  s08
0    0    0    0    0    0
1    1    1    1    1    1
2    0    2    2    0    2
3    0    0    3    3    0
4    0    0    0    4    4
```

If your index is numerical as in this sample, you can also do:

```
df.mul(df.index, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is definitely in the second cathegory. Once I get some more answers I will post the most efficient one.